# Order By different the others table id in MY SQL

Tags: mysql

Kindly help me with this.

For this do I need to join? Kindly guide me what is the query in MYSQL I would use for this.

I have one table with the name **_record** like the following:

```
________________
|id   | user_id |
|31   | 3315    |
|32   | 3316    |
|33   | 3317    |
________________
```

and the other table **_record_value** which is like below:

```
________________________
|id  | record_id |value |
|1   | 31        |xyz   |
|2   | 32        |xyz   |
|3   | 33        |xyz   |
________________________
```

I want that actually

```
Select value from _record_value ORDER BY _record.userid ASC;
```

How can I do this?

I am doing below write now

SELECT `field_value` 
FROM `jos_js_res_record_values` 
`record_id` INNER JOIN jos_js_res_record.id
            ON jos_js_res_record_values.record_id = jos_js_res_record.id
    ORDER BY jos_js_res_record.user_id ASC;

Comment: If 'id' could be used as a bridge linking two tables. You may join two tables using id then do that step.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT rv.value
    FROM _record_value rv
        INNER JOIN _record r
            ON rv.record_id = r.id
    ORDER BY r.user_id ASC;
```

Comment: what is r in the inner joi is it new column in the table & may be you abbreviate record_value as rv?

Comment: `r` and `rv` are aliases for the `_record` and `_record_value` tables, respectively.

Comment: Using the aliases makes it easier to specify your ON clause.  Otherwise, you'd end-up typing out "ON _record_value.record_id = _record.id"

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT rv.value
FROM _record_value rv
INNER JOIN _record r ON r.id = record_id
ORDER BY r.user_id;
```

Just curious, but why lead your table names with an underscore?

For the second part of your question, you asked about this query:

```
SELECT field_value 
FROM jos_js_res_record_values record_id 
INNER JOIN jos_js_res_record.id ON jos_js_res_record_values.record_id = jos_js_res_record.id 
ORDER BY jos_js_res_record.user_id ASC;
```

In this one, the "record_id" in your FROM clause would be treated as an alias for jos_js_res_record_values...which I'm pretty sure is not what you want.  Your JOIN syntax is very close to being correct.  I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT field_value 
FROM jos_js_res_record_values jrv
INNER JOIN jos_js_res_record jr ON jrv.record_id = jr.id 
ORDER BY jr.user_id ASC;
```

Comment: i am writing this query is it write or need changes?

SELECT `field_value` FROM `jos_js_res_record_values` 
`record_id` INNER JOIN jos_js_res_record.id
            ON jos_js_res_record_values.record_id = jos_js_res_record.id
    ORDER BY jos_js_res_record.user_id ASC;

Comment: @MohibSalahuddin, please add your code to your original answer...it's much easier to read that way.